# UITableView Image in the Cell Shrinks

Tags: ios, uitableview

The images in the tableview cell shrinks as soon as they are scrolled. They resize to the wanted size by reload.

The big stars have the size I want. The smaller ones appears during scrolling or on touch.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    NSArray *sectionData = self.dataSource[indexPath.section];
    SHFriendTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    [cell updateWithData:sectionData[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)updateWithData:(SHFriendTableCellData *)data {
    self.friendImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.friendImage.image = data.image;
    self.nameLabel.text = data.name;
}
```

Changing the content mode has no effect.

[image: Weird Table]

[image: Interface Builder Settings]

Comment: try to change UIViewContentModeScaleToFill to UIViewContentModeScaleToFit, the setting in the storyboard and the code is different I think. check the contentMode in the storyboard

Comment: Hi Bejibun. The change had no effect

Comment: Can you add NSLog(@"%f", cell.friendImage.frame.size.width): inside the updateWithData method? to check if the size is not changing everytime to update the cell

Comment: The width changes. From 85 to 73. I added auto layout constraints with and height to 85 with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a double reference to the image view. 
[image]

After deleting the issue was gone after I deleted the double reference.